# Swift: Error during protocol oriented approach. Error: cannot convert return expression of type 'I.Job' to return type 'ActualJob'

Tags: swift, protocols, type-mismatch, protocol-oriented

I have two interfaces `Controllerable` and `Interactorable` which should work together to achieve something. Following are the protocols:

```
protocol Controllerable {
    associatedtype Job: Decodable
    func getJob() -> Job
    func control(job: Job)
}

protocol Interactorable {
    associatedtype Job: Decodable
    func interact() -> Job
}
```

Here are the concrete types which conform to above protocols:
One thing to note here, `Controller` has an `Interactor` dependency to make things work.

```
struct ActualJob: Decodable {
    var id: String
}

class Controller<I: Interactorable>: Controllerable {
    typealias Job = ActualJob
    private var interactor: I

    init(interactor: I) {
        self.interactor = interactor
    }

    // MARK: Controllerable
    func control(job: ActualJob) {
        print("Controlling job: \(job.id)")
    }

    func getJob() -> ActualJob {
        return interactor.interact() //***** Line of contention ****
    }
}

class Interactor: Interactorable {
    typealias Job = ActualJob

    // MARK: Interactorable
    func interact() -> Job {
        return ActualJob(id: "xyz")
    }
}
```

Now, let's say there's a driver entity which drives the integration.

```
struct Someguy<C: Controllerable> {

    private var controller: C

    init(controller: C) {
        self.controller = controller
    }

    func doSomething() {
        let job = controller.getJob()
        controller.control(job: job)
    }
}
```

If you put all of this in the playground, you'd the see the following in the console:

> playground:30:27: error: cannot convert return expression of type
>   'I.Job' to return type 'ActualJob'
>
> return interactor.interact()
>
> ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
>
> as! ActualJob

So, the question is, why, if `Interactable.Job` and `Controllerable.Job` conform to the same types, should one get the above error?

**EDIT**
If I change the line of contention to

```
return interactor.interact() as! ActualJob
```

The error goes away, but why should this be needed? Does it not defeat the purpose of protocols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a constraint:

```
class Controller<I: Interactorable>: Controllerable where I.Job == ActualJob {
```

Without the constraint, `I.Job` can be anything, can't it? It could be `SomeOtherJob`, which is not convertible to `ActualJob`.

Comment: Both of them expect a Decodable, doesn't that suffice?

Comment: @justintime No. Two classes that conform to the same protocol are both compatible with that protocol, but not with each other. Let's say that `SomeOtherJob` has a `name` property instead of an `id` property. How can you convert `SomeOtherJob` to a `ActualJob`?

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying, `ActualJob` is convertible to `Decodable`, but `Decodable` might not be convertible to `ActualJob`. Will delve into this and get back. Thanks!